# Como configurar corretamente o caracter & no SQL Developer 17.3

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Olá amigos estou tentando fazer uma consulta sql no SQL Developer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE NOME_CLIENTE IN ('SALES & CIA AGUIAR', 'SAO JOAO')
```

A ferramenta está entendendo o caractere '&' como uma entrada de variável e assim não exibe o registro daquele cliente, gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de configurar isto para que quando o caractere '&' for passando dentro de aspas simples a ferramenta entenda que é um texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rode esse comando antes:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

E execute normalmente.

Ou reescreva seu comando assim:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE NOME_CLIENTE IN 
  ('SALES ' || chr(38) || ' CIA AGUIAR', 'SAO JOAO')
```

Comment: rodei o primeiro comando e funcionou , Muito obrigado!